# Maximizing count by location

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a dataset of particles in space, each in the range (x,y) in [0,1]^2. I have discretized meshes `x` and `y`, and am looking for an *efficient* way of finding the meshpoint containing the maximum particles. My first attempt:

```
max_count = -inf;
for i = 1:length(x)-1
    for j = 1:length(y)-1
        cnt = size(find(particles(:,1) >= x(i) & particles(:,1) <= x(i+1) & particles(:,2) >= y(j) & particles(:,2) <= y(j+1)),1);
        max_count = max(max_count,cnt);
    end
end
```

Of course, this was pretty slow. Much faster was to send the data to a `histogram2` call and extract the data from that

```
bins = histogram2(particles(:,1),particles(:,2),x,y);
max_count = max(max(bins.Values));
```

This is definitely faster, but still takes up a decent amount of time, given that I'm running this every iteration of a loop that goes on for thousands of steps. Is there a faster way? I've looked at the `discretize` function, but that only works for 1d arrays. Any sort of 2d analog to this function would be great.

Comment: `particles` is informed by the physical system I'm simulating, not much I can do there. Basically a bunch of x,y coordinates with some other information that's not relevant to this section of the code. FWIW I don't need the `histogram2` figure, I just need the binning function it provides.

Comment: Are the x and y meshes uniformly spaced?

Comment: Yes, uniformly spaced for now. Stretch goal would be to drop that requirement, but that's long term.

Comment: Another stretch goal would be to do this sort of maxfind with 3d coordinates, that is, given a 3d mesh, find the highest count of particles in a single (dx,dy,dz)-volume of the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`histcounts2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts2.html) to compute a bivariate histogram. It has more or less the same syntax as `histogram2`, but it doesn’t generate any graphics.

Comment: Great, this reduced the computation cost of this section to negligible. Much obliged!